# Convenient solution for using Symfony + SASS/Jade

Tags: php, symfony, sass, less, pug

Setup: PHP 5.4.8 + Symfony 2 dev + SASS + Jade.

How do you use it together?

I found a number of ways, but none of them seems good and clean. E.g. we have a jade.php project which has not been updated in over two years.

If it turns out that it is necessary to fall back to HAML and LESS, which is a good solution for them?

I already googled these things, but I want to know your personal experience with this issue, something about real production.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/index.html).

Comment: Ass there is no Jade Filter right now, this might not help much!